# Activerecord Rails 4 perform something like a join that still returns rows that don't have the association

Tags: actionscript-3, ruby-on-rails-4, join, left-join

If after reading my question you have a suggestion for a better title, please add a comment. I was having trouble succinctly saying what I wanted. I have a situation like this.

```
class Artist < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :album_artists
  has_many :albums, :through => :album_artists
end
class Album < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :album_artists
  has_many :artists, :through => :album_artists
end
class AlbumArist < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :album
  belongs_to :artist
end
```

I want a query on `artists` to return a result if either the artist's name or an album title that the artist is associated with match the query. I can achieve this with a join.

```
Artist.joins(:albums).where("artists.name like ? or albums.title like ?", query, query).uniq
```

What I would like to know is how to also return `artists` whose name matches the query but do not happen to have any `albums` associated with them. My goal is to do this all in a single query, I would prefer not to perform two sequential queries.

Please ask for more clarification if you need it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that `LEFT OUTER JOIN` is what I am looking for. I created scopes in the models like this:

```
class Artist < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :album_artists
  has_many :albums, :through => :album_artists

  scope :joins_albums, -> {joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN "album_artists" ON "album_artists"."artist_id" = "artists"."id" LEFT OUTER JOIN "albums" ON "albums"."id" = "album_artists"."album_id"')}
end
```

I use the scope in the query:

```
Artist.joins_albums.where("artists.name like ? or albums.title like ?", query, query).uniq
```

Now the results include `artists` whose names match the query even if they do not have any `albums` associated with them.